# How does map work in this context?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, enumerable

I am reading Matz's book "Programming Ruby", and in chapter 9, in the part about Threads, I read this code:

```
module Enumerable
  def concurrently
    map{|item| Thread.new{ yield item }}.each{|t| t.join}
  end
end
```

I know the `map` method is used for actions with arrays or collections, and in this example it shows  it without `self` or some `object`.

I'm confused how `map` works in this example.

Comment: You may be confused because you have seen this type of construct with `self.` tacked onto the front of a method.  As @mu explained, Ruby assumes the receiver is `self` when no receiver has been given.  So, why does one (often) see `self.` when it is not needed?  A kindly explanation is that the writer has added it for stylistic reasons. I think most would agree that adding anything that has no effect (causing the reader to ponder the reason for its presence) is to be avoided. The fact that you are asking this question may in itself be support for this argument.

Comment: I knowed about adding `self` when no receiver has been given, but Enumerable method `map` confused me, and also in previous example it showed with `self.each` then I was doubted how it works. I think using `self` it's more obviously and more clearly, in particular for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `map` is defined on any class which mixes in `Enumerable`.

It will be called on `self` from any `Enumerable` object, when you call `object.concurrently { |x| # whatever }` and the use of it is that it will spawn a large number of threads to evaluate the blocks.

Further, using `map` in the pattern from the book, means that you get the same behaviour as `Enumerable#map` with whatever additional effect is used before, around and after the `yield`. In this case, that is starting each block evaluation in its own thread.

Answer (score 5):

Calling a method without an explicit receiver calls the method on `self` so even though "it shows without `self`" the `self` is implicitly present as the default receiver. That method is more or less the same as:

```
def concurrently
  self.map{|item| Thread.new{ yield item }}.each{|t| t.join}
 #^^^^^ This is implicit.
end
```